# AJAX Page with Boostrap Modal Form - Submit don't work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, modal-dialog

i searched a lot about this problem, but I didn't find a solution, yet.

At first a short description about my setup to make my problem clearer.

- Settings.php Page with a Menu, where you can select different settings categories
- By clicking on one menu point the corresponding loads by ajax and is displayed.

`$('#content').load("http://"+ document.domain + "/domainhere/settings/menupoint1.php");`

- On the menupont1.php page I got a list with mysql data.
- I implemented a "edit" button for each row - while clicking on the edit button, a boostrap modal appears with a form and the corresponding data filled in and ready to edit.
- When i now click on "Save changes", the POST-Request is always empty.

To realize the form submit, I already tried several codes:

e.g.:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
        }
    });
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $('#editform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: url, //this is the submit URL
            type: 'GET', //or POST
            data: $('#editform').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                 alert('successfully submitted')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

At the moment:

```
while($xy= $xysql->fetch_assoc()) {
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-<?php echo $xy["id"] ?>" [..]>
<button id="submit>" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</div>

<script>
                     $(function() {
                        $('button#submit').click(function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                            url: './test2.php',
                            data: $('form#modal-form').serialize(),
                                success: function(msg){
                                        $('#test').html(msg)
                                    $('#form-content').modal('hide');   
                                    },
                            error: function(){
                                alert('failure');
                                }
                                });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
```

Maybe someone here could help me out with this problem?
thank you very much :)

Comment: how do you send the data to the modal? Or do you have a modal for each row?

Comment: Your second attempt looks quite good. Do you get the message 'successfully submitted'?

Comment: do you get a reasonable output if you `console.log($('#editform'));`?

Comment: Hi @Jeff, i have a modal for each row.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware - yeha i got it. But my update-row.php (the file which updates the sql) don't get the POST-Variables-Value e.g. $id = NULL

Comment: That's then the reason why it's not working. You can only have _one_ element with the same id. So js doens't know which one of the many to pick, so it picks either first or last one.

Comment: @Jeff: Nop, no output.

Comment: Make it only _one_ modal and fill it's content when clicking on edit.

Comment: Ah @Jeff I'll try it! :D

Comment: with id i meant `#editform`

Comment: _OR_ give each modal an individual unique id. like `editform1`, `editform2`,.. and bind the `on('submit')`  on a classname. (That's easier to implement.)

Comment: Hi @Jeff: My Modals have all their own id.
But not quite sure about the on("submit") part..

Comment: @Jeff: May you can have a look at my updated description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up a minimal example of how this would work:

example html of two modals, which are produced in a loop in your case.
I've now done it without a unique id, but with selecting via class.

```
<div class="modal">
          <!-- // this classname is new and important -->
   <form class="editform">
     <input name="test" value="value1">
     <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>   
   </form>
</div>

<div class="modal">
   <form class="editform">
     <input name="test" value="value2">
     <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>   
   </form>
</div>
```

Your javascript would be something like this:

```
$(function() {
   var formsAll = $('.editform');
                          // changed this to onSubmit, because it's easier to implement the preventDefault!
   formsAll.on('submit',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var formData = $(this).serialize();
       console.log(formData);
       // add your ajax call here.
       // note, that we already have the formData, it would be "data: formData," in ajax.

   });
});
```

Note, that I don't have your real html structure, so details might vary. But you get the idea.

also available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/a0qhgmsb/16/

Comment: Thank you very much. But sadly i still dont get it.
Could you have a look here?

https://jsfiddle.net/umwor52h/